# Using parameters for search

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, sql-like

I have the tables `customer` - with `customerid` and `phone number`, 
and `calls` - with `phone numbers` and `date`.

I need to find the customer's phone number in the calls table. 
now the thing is - in the calls table the phone number can be in different ways-

If I need to search for one value I would do that by using `(where phone like %somenumber%')`, but I need to search for all the numbers
- So I think I need to do that with parameter- but I don't know how ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your programmimg language ? Or do you need mysql query ?

Comment: right, sorry - using SQL server. but i think if i'll see it in Mysql - i will manage it so that t will work for the mssql

Comment: concider dropping msysql tag to ease search and put what your efforts so far are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table for search values. Say it is:

```
filtertable(phone varchar(20))
```

Now you can join the filtertable on calls table like:

```
select * from calls c
join filtertable f on c.phone like '%' + f.phone + '%'
```

If you have this logic in stored proc you can create table valued type and pass filtertable to your proc. See here for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: Thanks,great  solution!